# How to increase Node.js server's default response timeout duration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

In my Node.js API I am getting 504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT after 1 minute.

My API endpoint is doing a heavy operation - it takes from 1 to 2 minutes to execute it completely and return a response. However, after 1 minute, a 504 response is automatically returned.

I have tried with:

```
server.timeout = 120000;
```

But still it's not waiting for 120 seconds.

I also tried with:

```
req.setTimeout(120000);
```

But this again is not working.

I'm using `http.createServer()`.

Comment: Are you using express (web framework) or `http.createServer()`?

Comment: I m using http.createServer(app)

Comment: `const server = http.createServer(); server.timeout = 3000`

Comment: I have tried with this but its is not working

Comment: Timeout configurations were changed in several versions. Which version of nodejs do you use?

Comment: i m using latest version and after printing server.timeout  am getting 0 value

Comment: So 16 I assume - worth updating question with this info

Comment: Your Node app is behind a reverse proxy, like Nginx or AWS' ELB. Configure that to have a higher timeout. The reverse proxy is working fine but it expected an answer from the upstream (your Node app) sooner, got bored and decided to call it quits.

Comment: From the error it appears that your GATEWAY is timing out. Not node.js. If nodejs timeout it would not respond with GATEWAY TIMEOUT. Gateways are services in front of your node.js like an Nginx server, a load balancer or a DDOS protection service like Cloudfront

Answer (score 0):

There are a few flags in Nodejs 16, that relates to timeouts and you need to make sure that everyone of them is set properly for your needs:

- `timeout` - socket timeout with default `0`
- `headersTimeout` - timeout for retrieving headers with default `60000`
- `requestTimeout` - timeout for entire request with default `0`